# Hibernate, subclassing because of calculated fields (Hibernate 2.8.1)

Tags: hibernate, mapping, subclassing

I have a view in my db e.g **view1** and I need to use this view up to making report **view1report** with some calculated fields, say AplusB

(of course I want to handle them as objects by Hibernate)

**Example**

```
view1
    int a
    int b
---    
view1report extends view1
    int AplusB
....
public int setAplusB() { ... my own logic ...}
```

**Question**

- A. Can it be solved by Hibernate ?

If yes

- B. How can I build up my hmb.xml to express the subclassing ?
- C. AND last but not least how can use my own logic in the setters of calculated fields ?

(The reason why i want to separate them the additional calculated fields)

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and execute in db. Now create a POJO to map view. if you are mapping entities using HBM, create hbm file and map it as you are mapping Table. and if you are using annotation, create annotated class with mapping respective field

And in your mapped class, create one more file(if annotated class, add `@Transient` annotation

```
public int aplusb;
```

in its getter method, return sum of a and b.

```
return a+b;
```

This will work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that we write hbm.xml for the views ( 1 View - 1 Entity), but I dont know how to describe the similar cases above in hbm.xml

Comment: Same as we are doing for table, consider view as table and map it. It will work same as table work. Note:Make sure, when you export your schema, it will create table

Comment: Can you cite a hbm.xml example which can implement the solution of my problem ? Because I cant see how can I set followings - Inhertance, the subclass (view1report) doesnt exists in the db (because it only holds calculated values) - and hbm generates the getters, setters as well, when i want to define my setter or getters with with specific logic. Sorry If i was not clear enough at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out that I dont need to configure the hbm.xml to generate subclasses (which has just calculated fields).
I just need to subclass the hibernate generated class by myself programatically.

It was a good lesson.

Those who did not follow this discussion my idea was that I will generate the *view1report* class by hbm2java as well (see the example) which has only calculated fields based on superclass *view1*.